# Adding the version system and table history to the table in the code first method

Tags: c#, ef-code-first

I need to use the system version property and the table history of the SQL in the code-first method, so that one, by using a token, when a record was changed between selection and editing, it gives an error and does not save the changes, and two, when My record was changed in the employee table, it will automatically save a new record in the employee History table, and by using the start Date and end Date fields, you can find out how long this value has been in the main table.

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int pk Employee { get; set; }
        public string User Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public Boolean Mobile Is Active { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Boolean Email Is Active { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
    public class Employee History
    {
    public int pk Employee { get; set; }
    public string User Name { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public Boolean Mobile Is Active { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public Boolean Email Is Active { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Last Name { get; set; }
    public Date Time StartDate { get; set; }
    public Date Time End Date { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee", e => e.IsTemporal());
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?